# use bufferedReader or scanner to read space seperated lines

Tags: java, performance

I know scanner is cleaner and easy to use. But, if performance is topmost concern, should we always use BufferedReader?

I mean if i have to read something line by line. I'll always go for BufferedReader. But if i need to parse that line based on  space(" ") or comma(","), what should i opt, i have two options:

1. Split string returned by bufferedReader. And if required format is int, convert String[] to int[].
2. Use sc.nextInt()in loop.

2nd option is ofcourse cleaner and slower than bufferedReader. But i know that split is also a slow function and so is conversion of string[] to int[].

What should i do

Comment: You only need a solution that's fast enough for your data. You'll need a lot of data before the difference has any impact. And in that case you can measure and tune and find out for yourself

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (Donald Knuth). It is mainly a matter of taste and how well you implement it. Both strategies can be arbitrarily slow or fast, depending on how you use them. Personally, I'd prefer not to use `Scanner`, but do whatever you want to do.

Comment: i can't check this difference by myself. But If this difference is not of much scale, one should always use scanner as it does parsing for you by itself and of course code is cleaner.